# Applying change event on j-Query Data-Table Search Box?

Tags: events, search, datatables

I have j-Query data-table with many records and I have builtin search-box. What I am trying is to sum all values in all the  `tds` which have `class="amount"`. It's happening succesfully. Now, the problem is search box. I want to sum the values of `tds` with class name `amount` which are only visible. I tried many ways but nothing worked Following is my code:

```
 var salaryTable =  $('#tblSalary').DataTable();

 salaryTable.on('search', function () {

      var sum = 0;

       $(".amount").each(function() {
             var value = $(this).text();
             if(!isNaN(value) && value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseFloat(value);
             }
       });

       alert(sum);
 });
```

This logic is not working as expected. How can I solve this or What am I doing wrong? Is there any better approach?

**Update:** The problem is when I search something it gives me total of visible and invisible records. When I clear the search box with backspace, it gives me total of all records where were visible before.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want visible elements with class amount you could use the jQuery :visible selector

```
$(".amount:visible").each(...)
```

jQuery docs https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Its right. But the problem is when I search something it gives me total of visible and invisible records. When I clear the search box with backspace, it gives me total of all records where were visible before.

Comment: @JohnAdam your question is unclear to me. I mean, if your search box is clear, and you have all records, then you do want to get a total of all records that have the amount class right?